# $x(y^2+u)u_x-y(x^2+u)u_y=(x^2-y^2)u$ with $u(x,-x)=1$ for $x>0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Not homework but exercices I like to do...

Solve $x(y^2+u)u_x-y(x^2+u)u_y=(x^2-y^2)u$ with $u(x,-x)=1\;x>0$

Manipulating the auxiliar system of ODEs $\dfrac{dx}{x(y^2+u)}=\dfrac{dy}{-y(x^2+u)}=\dfrac{du}{(x^2-y^2)u}$

I get a pretty simplified expression $(x+y)d(x^2+y^2)=2du$ that I see unusable to find the general solution. I found no better expression. I know the solution has a not very complicated closed form, but I am stuck... Help appreciated.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Left details to you:
$$\dfrac{x\ dx}{x^2y^2+x^2u}=\dfrac{y\ dy}{-x^2y^2-uy^2}=\dfrac{du}{(x^2-y^2)u}$$
$$\dfrac{x\ dx+y\ dy}{x^2y^2+x^2u-x^2y^2-uy^2}=\dfrac{du}{(x^2-y^2)u}$$
$$\color{blue}{d(x^2+y^2)=2du}$$
$$\dfrac{y\ dx}{xy(y^2+u)}=\dfrac{x\ dy}{-xy(x^2+u)}=\dfrac{du}{(x^2-y^2)u}$$
$$\dfrac{y\ dx + x\ dy}{xy(y^2-x^2)}=\dfrac{du}{(x^2-y^2)u}$$
$$\color{blue}{\dfrac{d(xy)}{xy}=-\dfrac{du}{u}}$$

Answer (score 2):

This is a Lagrange method, assuming you know how to do it. I'll give you a **hint** to find $\varphi$ and then you can similarly find $\psi$, check the Jacobian and solve it.
$$ \frac{\lambda dx + \mu dy + \nu du}{\lambda x(y^2+u)-\mu y(x^2+u)+\nu u(x^2-y^2)} = \frac{dx}{x(y^2+u)}=\frac{dy}{-y(x^2+u)}=\frac{du}{u(x^2-y^2)}$$ 
For $\lambda=x$, $\mu=y$ and $\nu=-1$ you get 
$$ \varphi_x=x \quad \varphi_y=y \quad \varphi_u=-1 $$
and solve it to get $\varphi(x,y,u)=\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{2}-u$.

Comment: I think that $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are the surfaces that determine the characteristics. I don't see why the partials of $\varphi$ are those.